# How to Update a table row from a Wordpress page

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to update a row from one table in Wp database, all this from a page in wordpress. I'm using a plugin that allows me to write php inside the page, and I'm writing this:

```
$ident = $_GET['id'];
echo $ident;

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . ' wp_cf7dbplugin_submits';

$data = array(
 'field_name' => 'p'
);
$where = array( 'submit_time' => $ident );
$format = array( '%s', '%d' );
$where_format = array( '%d' );

$wpdb->update( $table_name, $data, $where, $format, $where_format );
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: your $table_name is `$wpdb->prefix . 'wp_cf7dbplugin_submits';` which assuming prefix is `wp_`, it will result in `wp_wp_cf7dbplugin_submits`. is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

`$wpdb->prefix` is your database prefix. By default this is 'wp_'.

That means that in your code the following line:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . ' wp_cf7dbplugin_submits';
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$table_name = 'wp_ wp_cf7dbplugin_submits';
```

You need to remove the duplicate prefix and space before the text.

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cf7dbplugin_submits';
```

I'd also look into another solution for adding the code. Using a plugin to allow PHP in the editor is a bad idea.